# Using regex, how to replace white space with no characters?

Tags: regex

How to replace from regex many empty/blank characters with none? ex:

```
<div class="someClass" id="someID"> 
...bunch of elements/content 
<input type="button" name="myInput" id="inputID" title="myInput Title" /> 
...bunch of elements/content 
</div>
```

when replaced :

```
<a class="myselector" rel="I need this value"></a><div class="someClass" id="someID">...bunch of elements/content<input type="button" name="myInput" id="inputID" title="myInput Title" />...bunch of elements/content</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using regular expressions to manipulate/parse HTML/XHTML.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov what should I be using?

Comment: @Gandalf, an HTML DOM/parsing library, like BeautifulSoup or lxml in Python, or HTML Agility Pack in C#.

Comment: @Max Shawabkeh does any of those parse/minify javasciprt/HTML/php also in the same file?

Comment: Not natively, but writing a minifier in them may be easier than doing it using regex. Also, Yahoo has some command line Java tools for minifying JS/CSS that can be used as middleware. You're out of luck for parsing PHP, though. Probably has to be done as a preprocessing step, since it's not strictly HTML.

Comment: What's the purpose of minifying PHP?

Comment: I wouldn't want to minify PHP but the whole file,  the file usually consists of PHP, JS and HTML. So if I copy the content of the whole file to let say javascript minifier, then I get syntax error after the code is minified, so I'm looking for something that can handle php as well leave it be as it is or whatever just don't break down the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `\s+` will match one or more whitespace characters. Replace it with an empty string to remove them. E.g., in Python:

```
cleaned = re.sub(r'\s+', '', original)
```

If you plan to do this to HTML, you may damage it. At least replace with a single space instead:

```
cleaned = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', original)
```

Or use a proper HTML manipulation library.

Comment: Note that `\s` does not just represent the space character but whitespace characters in general.

Comment: Won't this bork anything within a <pre> tag?  (I know... you're just answering the question... and you did disclaim it with "use a proper HTML manipulation library")