# Regex replace space in string

Tags: php, regex, replace

I'm messing about with the LESS PHP parser to get it to replace 4 colour hex codes found in IE filters. What I want to do is replace stuff like this: `#ff7755 33` with `#ff775533` ie. remove all the spaces in it. Obviously the characters can vary as they're colour codes. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708946/using-regex-how-to-replace-white-space-with-no-characters) which is very close to what I want.

Right now, I have this regex which finds the string just fine:

`(#([0-9a-f]){6}\s[0-9a-f]{2})`

All I need now is the regex to put in the replace argument of `preg_replace()`.

Comment: can you just do a regular string replace after you have found the string?

Comment: I could, but I don't know how to do it, as the entire string needs to be passed back to a `return`, not just the found/replaced bit. Or did I misunderstand you here?

Comment: Might as well just `$str = preg_replace("/ /", "", $str);` if you already know it's definitely a valid color code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(#[0-9a-f]{6}) ([0-9a-f]{2})/i','$1$2',$yourSource);
```

Comment: Thank you so much yes123! I've been struggling with this for hours - I just can't get my head around regex yet. Damn head.

Answer (score 2):

The first example in the PHP manual would seem to be exactly what you are trying to do:

```
<?php
$string = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}1,$3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Of course for you it is:

```
<?php
$string = '#ff7755 33';
$pattern = '/(#[0-9a-f]{6})\s([0-9a-f]{2})/i';
$replacement = '${1}$2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Comment: No need to write `${1}` instead of `$1`. Apart from that +1.

Comment: @nikic: It was copy-paste from the PHP manual.  The manual needed it because it was putting the 1 in there and since it does no harm I left it alone.

Comment: You are right, you can use it. I just don't like it if people add additional parentheses (or braces here). I mean, you could as well write `${'var'}` instead of `$var` and occasionally you will indeed do so, but normally I would consider `${'var'}` (or `${1}`) bad style :)

Comment: I should have read harder. I missed this I think because I have no clue about regex. I'll get there one day!